# How to show whatsapp with correct user-agent

Tags: android, webview

I want to show whatsapp web in my webview. I was use an user agent, but i still can't to open it. Please help to to show the whatsapp web in my webview.

This is my code:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
String agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.121 Safari/537.36"; 
myWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(agent);
```

What should I do?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. If anybody resolved it, can you please let me know some hints ?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the logcat and I saw errors like

> cannot call determinedvisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid

I fixed the issue by adding:

```
simpleWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

to the code and the web view is working.